# How to set browser client area size using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found how to set browser window size at Selenium Issue Management system (see [Browser window control #174](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/174)):

```
Window window = driver.manage().window();
window.setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
window.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

But this solution sets size for whole window (title bar, bookmarks bar, borders etc.), so client area has different sizes in different browsers. Is there any way to simply set the same value for popular browsers (Chrome, FireFox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari)? It will be great if I don't need to eval JavaScript.

Comment: A solution could be to switch window via `driver.get()` and then manage `window` size when you are on that area. Did you think about this possibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier with a piece of Javascipt, but since you asked without:

```
Dimension win_size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
int inner_width = Integer.parseInt(html.getAttribute("clientWidth"));
int inner_height = Integer.parseInt(html.getAttribute("clientHeight"));

// set the inner size of the window to 400 x 400 (scrollbar excluded)
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(
    win_size.width + (400 - inner_width),
    win_size.height + (400 - inner_height)
));
```

And with a piece of Javascript just in case:

```
ArrayList padding = (ArrayList)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
  "return [window.outerWidth-window.innerWidth, window.outerHeight-window.innerHeight];");

// set the inner size of the window to 400 x 400 (scrollbar included)
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(
    (int)(400 + (Long)padding.get(0)),
    (int)(400 + (Long)padding.get(1))
));
```

Comment: Is this work if I call it on blank page? Steps: launch browser, see default page (e.g. blank), set size, navigate to concrete page <- this page should has fixed size.

Comment: The first example probably doesn't work with a blank page, however the second should work.