# FirefoxDriver takes screenshots with different than window sizes

Tags: java, image, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to take screenshot in Firefox browser and compare it with already saved on my pc image.

1) There is my firefox option:

```
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.setHeadless(true);
            options.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
            System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
            System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().setSizes(1440, 900);
```

2) Method which I use for taking a screenshot:

```
            driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

The final image dimensions is 1440 x 826 instead of excpected 1440 x 900 pixels.

The difference is 74 pixels (1.96 centimeters).

My questions are:

1) Why it happened?

2) How to solve this issue?

Note:

- selenium version: 4.0.0-alpha-3
- testNG version: 7.0.0
- firefox version: 74.0.0
- this issue reproduced only in Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. For this I changed a client area size in Firefox using JavaScript and Selenium WebDriver.The next article was very helpfull for me during resolving.

- [How to set browser client area size using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333708/how-to-set-browser-client-area-size-using-selenium-webdriver)

But there is one thing, which I wanna pay your attention - before change view port size be assured that browser is not in full screen mode(if it is - you can have some inaccuracyes with final sizes). So it is really matter.